# html element h1 with links as background image show them in one line

Tags: html, css

I have an H1 element that contains many links, these links have unique classes.

I need to define the css classes in such a way that each class will have it's corresponding image as background, that will make the image as link.

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2gob0f6/1/)

HTML:

```
 <h1 class="title">
    My Title<a class="cl1" href="http://www.google.com" />
    <a class="cl2" href="http://www.google.com" />
    <a class="cl3" href="http://www.google.com" />
    <a class="cl4" href="http://www.google.com" />        
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
    .title a.cl1 {
    display:block;
    background-image: url("http://oi61.tinypic.com/2sbmuxy.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
    }

    .title a.cl2 {
    display:block;
    background-image: url("http://oi61.tinypic.com/2sbmuxy.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
    }

    .title a.cl3 {
    display:block;
    background-image: url("http://oi61.tinypic.com/2sbmuxy.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
    }

   .title a.cl4 {
   display:block;
    background-image: url("http://oi61.tinypic.com/2sbmuxy.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
    }
```

My question: how can I display the links in one line? Now are shown one under each other.

Comment: There's no logical, semantic or SEO reason to use an `h1` there...use a div instead.

Comment: I know, unfortunately I cannot change it. Is coming as such from a 3'rd party service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;` in every class for the `a` elements.
You can also add `vertical-align: middle` to have the links centered in the h1 tag.

Comment: How can I add them inline but under the H1 text ?

Comment: I don't think that you can do that, unfortunately the "My Title" text is not wrapped in an html element.I know it's ugly but maybe you can change the generated code with jquery and insert a `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block` for the `a` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline-block;`

It was a little tough to follow what you're looking to do, but I believe this is it.

http://jsfiddle.net/y2gob0f6/4/

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic since you cannot change the HTML. Using `float: right;` on all the `a` elements should help avoid whitespace issues but you would need to control the width of the container to figure out how to keep things in flow and CSS may need to be updated each time the content was updated. If you use `inline-block`, you MAY want `font-size: 0` on the `h1` tag to avoid whitespace but you cannot do that since you have text that needs to display. `inline-block` may be the safest way to go, unfortunately.

See [this link](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) for more details on the whitespace issue